# How to update text of a presented view controller after a delay?

Tags: ios, objective-c

As we see in this code, `Text` should be "Program Started" after 3 seconds, but in the view it is still stuck in "Hello World". Does anyone have a solution for this?

```
NSString *Text = @"Hello World";
NSLog(Text); // Hello World
UIViewController *vc = [HelloWorldViewFactory createWithText:Text];
vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor systemBackgroundColor];
[vc.sheetPresentationController setPreferredCornerRadius:0];
[vc.sheetPresentationController setDetents:@[UISheetPresentationControllerDetent.mediumDetent]];
[vc.sheetPresentationController setPrefersScrollingExpandsWhenScrolledToEdge:false];
[UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    Text = @"Program started";
});
NSLog(Text); // Program started
```

Comment: You are simply changing the local variable `Text`. You need to pass the updated text to the view controller. Also note that you are trying to change the text after 0.1 seconds, not 3 seconds.

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Comment: It can't be done with your current code since all you have is a `UIViewController` reference. You need a subclass of `UIViewController` that has some method or property that you can update with the new text.

Comment: Show me your method, I have no idea about the stuff that you are saying!

Comment: Update your question with relevant portions of your `HelloWorldViewFactory createWithText:` method. That will make it a lot easier to show a relevant solution.

Comment: This is a swift view!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out in comments you are not assigning a new text on your view so you can not see the change on your screen. You need to have a way to update text on your view.

Using a direct way you could assign a new text through your view controller. Something like this:

```
[vc assignNewText: @"Program started"];
// Instead of Text = @"Program started";
```

But to do so you will need access to your view controller as your own subclass (which is not included in your question but we can assume it exists). If it is called `HelloWorldViewController` then:

```
HelloWorldViewController *vc = [HelloWorldViewFactory createWithText:Text];
// Instead of UIViewController *vc = [HelloWorldViewFactory createWithText:Text];
```

We should also ensure that the method to create your view controller is actually defined to return this type of view. It should be:

```
// In @interface of HelloWorldViewFactory
+ (HelloWorldViewController *)createWithText:(NSString *)text;
// In @implementation of HelloWorldViewFactory
+ (HelloWorldViewController *)createWithText:(NSString *)text {
```

And a method to assign new text should be added to your `HelloWorldViewController`. Again assuming a lot there could be a label referenced through `textLabel` which displays your text.

```
@implementation HelloWorldViewController

- (void)assignNewText:(NSString *)text {
    self.textLabel.text = text;
}


@end
```